# I want to edit my fortran generated file in fortran

Tags: linux, file, fortran, editing, fortran95

I have a fortran 95 program, which writes an array in this form:

```
do temp = 1, temp_final 
  do MC = 1, N_MC
    do x = 0, N
      do y = 0, M
        write(1,*) x, y, array(x,y)
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
    write(1,*) T
    T = T - temp*factor
enddo
```

In my program, I am writing these values to a file, but between two temperature values, I am writing more than one time(but N_MC times) x, y array(x,y) values, as they are inside MC loop, going upto N_MC steps.

As file is only generated, and program takes very long time to run, so if you can suggest any technique to edit already generated file and to keep only first set of values and transfer them to another file or edit the parent file, and keep the changes.

My file looks like this

```
 Temp  0.69999999999999998 !(initial value)
       0           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           2  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           3   1.0000000000000000     
       0           4   1.0000000000000000          
       1           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       1           1   1.0000000000000000     
       1           2   1.0000000000000000     
       1           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       1           4  -1.0000000000000000         
       2           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           1   1.0000000000000000     
       2           2  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           3   1.0000000000000000     
       2           4   1.0000000000000000         
       3           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           2   1.0000000000000000     
       3           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           4  -1.0000000000000000     

       0           0   1.0000000000000000     
       0           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           2   1.0000000000000000     
       0           3   1.0000000000000000     
       0           4  -1.0000000000000000          
       1           0   1.0000000000000000     
       1           1   1.0000000000000000     
       1           2   1.0000000000000000     
       1           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       1           4  -1.0000000000000000         
       2           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           1   1.0000000000000000     
       2           2  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           3   1.0000000000000000     
       2           4   1.0000000000000000         
       3           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           2   1.0000000000000000     
       3           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           4  -1.0000000000000000
       ..........       
        N_MC-2 times (as two sets are already shown) !( after that there is new temp having new array values)

 Temp  0.59999999999999998  ! like this, I am having array values for diff. temp
 .
 .
 .
 Temp  0.09999999999999998 !(final vaule)
```

I want to keep first set of values only not after that .......... N_MC times values between successive values of temp.

I don't know how to call a file and remove particular section, which I don't want and save it again.

**NB**

I want to transfer only first set of values 0-3, 0-9, array(i,j)

```
       0           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           2  -1.0000000000000000     
       0           3   1.0000000000000000     
       0           4   1.0000000000000000          
       1           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       1           1   1.0000000000000000     
       1           2   1.0000000000000000     
       1           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       1           4  -1.0000000000000000         
       2           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           1   1.0000000000000000     
       2           2  -1.0000000000000000     
       2           3   1.0000000000000000     
       2           4   1.0000000000000000         
       3           0  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           1  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           2   1.0000000000000000     
       3           3  -1.0000000000000000     
       3           4  -1.0000000000000000
       ! Not after that for Temp = 0.6999999999990
```

to a file for a single temperature.

Comment: its not clear what you want to keep, but in any case as a general principle (regardless of language) to delete something from a file you rewrite the entire file, omitting what you want deleted.  For this example i suspect your best approach is to simply hold what you need in memory and write the entire file anew each time.

Comment: @george File is very large.

Comment: If you are on a Linux-like platform familiarise yourself with utilities such as `grep`, `split`, `cut` which can all be used to get bits out of files.  If you're on a Windows-like platform find out the local equivalents.

Comment: Not quite a direct answer, but inverting the "do x" and "do y" loops might speed things up a bit since your code will be able to more directly trace the "array".  Of course, you'll have to keep in mind that this changes the order of the output.

Answer (score 0):

When you close and reopen an existing Fortran file you can say where to position the first write.

```
open(unit, action='write', position='append')
```

appends your new writes at the end, while

```
open(unit, action='write', position='rewind', status='replace')
```

will erase the existing contents and start writing at the beginning.

Comment: Hello, welcome on this site. Please be sure to read the help and to make yourself  familiar with the usual form of answers and the formatting features. I will do some basic formatting in your first post, but it still appears to me somewhat unclear how this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you know exactly how many lines you want to keep (`N_MC*N*M`?), for the sake of giving an answer you can use let's say you want to keep

```
KeepLines=N_MC*N*M
```

What you can do then is calling a read statement with the following open statement and right away a write statement:

```
open (file="/path/yourBigFile", unit=13, access="sequential", status="old", action="read")  
open(unit=12, file="/path/yourSmallerFile", status="new", position="append", action="write")  
do i=0,KeepLines-1  !!Watch out for indexes here and be sure to have defined xx,yy, arr  
    read(13,*) xx,yy,arr  
    write(12,*) xx,yy,arr  
enddo
```

If you need not only the first chunk but all different chunks this approach is easily generalizable: just put a do-loop on temp between the two open statements and make an array for the names of your smaller files such that in the second open statement you can say something like `file=name(temp)`.